# Activeadmin can can authorization error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, cancan

Getting following error on calling **controller.load_and_authorize_resource**

```
 protected method `authorize!' called for #<Admin::ProjectsController:0x1405de80>
```

This is happening right after the bundle update.

Gem file contains the following entry,

```
 gem "activeadmin" , git: 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
```

active admin version: 0.5.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you mention activeadmin github repo as a source you are using version 0.6.0

Answer (score 4):

For ActiveAdmin v0.6.0 they added adapters according to this [ticket](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1817)

See updated [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html)

Comment: thanks Andrey for your time. Can you tell me how should I use same method instead of custom cancan adapter?